# NUnit SetUp and TearDown

Tags: .net, unit-testing, nunit

I have some experience in MS Test but new to NUnit.

1. Whether NUnit [Setup] is corresponding to [ClassInitialize] or [TestInitialize] in MS Test?
2. What is the NUnit attribute corresponding to [TestInitialize]?

REFERENCE:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873191/testinitialize-gets-fired-for-every-test-in-my-visual-studio-unit-tests
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602288/nunit-testcontext-currentcontext-test-not-working

Comment: Though the site is about XUnit, you can get some of the most used ones here: http://xunit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Comparisons

Answer (score 2):

NUnit [SetUp] corresponds to [TestInitialize].

For [ClassInitialize], use [TestFixtureSetUp] in NUnit.

The [complete list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/nnaderi/comparing-the-mstest-and-nunit-frameworks) can be found by a simple search. (a little old tho)

Answer (score 0):

NUnit parallel to `[ClassInitialize]` is `[OneTimeSetup]`

- see https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/attributes/onetimesetup.html

Parallel to `[TestInitialize]` is `[Setup]`

- see https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/attributes/setup.html